# TFRecord parsing for 3-D features

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588382/how-to-convert-float-array-list-to-tfrecord), but what if my feature shape is 3-D? Instead of prices `(1,288)`, it is `(1,288,3)` for example. What should I put as the shape of `tf.io.FixedLenFeature()`? Is it `tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[288,3], tf.float32)` or `tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=[864], tf.float32)` or anything else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you can do this. One is using a [BytesList](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/BytesList) feature

```py
def _bytes_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(
    bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

and the other is using a [FloatList](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/FloatList) feature

```py
def _float_feature(value):
  return tf.train.Feature(
    float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value))
```

**Example**:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# make some data
img = np.random.normal(size=(5, 3))
img = img.astype(np.float32)

writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter("/tmp/data.tfrec")

example = tf.train.Example(
  features=tf.train.Features(
    feature = {
      "img_b": _bytes_feature(img.tobytes()),
      "img_f": _float_feature(img.flatten()),
    }))

writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()

def parse_fn(example):
  features = {
    "img_b": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    "img_f": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([5, 3], tf.float32),
  }
  parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, features)
  img_b = tf.io.decode_raw(
      parsed_example['img_b'],
      out_type=tf.float32)
  img_b = tf.reshape(img_b, (5, 3))
  img_f = parsed_example['img_f']
  return img_b, img_f
```

Let's import the data and see if it worked

```py
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(["/tmp/data.tfrec"])
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn).batch(1)

arr_b, arr_f = next(iter(dataset))

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(arr_b.numpy(), arr_f.numpy())
# passes
```

This assumes that you know the shape of your images and that they are all the same shape.